# How to remove NoRemoteRepositoryException log when spring cloud config server can't connect to remote git repo?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

There are spring cloud config client and server, and I don't want server show error log when server can't connect to remote git repo. Is there any method to make it?

Server side log:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoRemoteRepositoryException: ssh://git@cedt-icg-bitbucketcli.nam.nsroot.net:7999/primewire/configuserapp12423.git: Repository not foundThe requested repository does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.cleanNotFound(TransportGitSsh.java:208) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-3.5.3.201412180710-r.jar:3.5.3.201412180710-r]
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:288) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-3.5.3.201412180710-r.jar:3.5.3.201412180710-r]
```

Comment: Why do you not want to show the error? You can adjust the logging.

Comment: @spencergibb There is a scenario that I only need client connect to server without connecting to remote git. So I don't want error log in this case. 
Here is  a problem, this error log is from embedded tomcat and I wonder how to config this embedded tomcat log.
Thx~